# Create a tag as a bindable property

Tags: data-binding, xamarin.forms

Is there an alternative for a Tag Bindable Property?
A tag property is available in WPF. However, it does not exist in Xamarin.Forms.

I would like to create a bindable context between two elements.
 Specifically, I would like to bind a label's Tag property to an entry's Text property.

I have attempted the following:

**Tag Property**

```
public class TagBehavior
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty TagProperty = BindableProperty.CreateAttached<TagBehavior, BindableObject>(
           bindableObject => TagBehavior.GetTag(bindableObject),
           null, /* default value */
           BindingMode.OneWay,
           null,
           (bo, old, @new) => TagBehavior.OnCompletedChanged(bo, old, @new),
           null,
           null);

    public static BindableObject GetTag(BindableObject bindableObject)
    {
        return (BindableObject)bindableObject.GetValue(TagBehavior.TagProperty);
    }

    public static void SetTag(BindableObject bindingObject, BindableObject value)
    {
        bindingObject.SetValue(TagBehavior.TagProperty, value);
    }

    public static void OnCompletedChanged(BindableObject bindableObject, BindableObject oldValue, BindableObject newValue)
    {
        //var tag = TagBehavior.GetTag(entry);

        //if (tag != null)
        //{
        //    Debug.WriteLine("TODO - Handle tag's value change event");
        //}
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
xmlns:Behaviors="clr-namespace:ViewMenu.Behaviors;assembly=ViewMenu"
```

. . .

```
<Entry x:Name="textBox1" BindingContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}" Text="{Binding Path=Content1}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" >
  <Entry.Behaviors>
    <Behaviors:TextBoxFocusBehavior />
  </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>

<Label x:Name="label1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
       Behaviors:TagBehavior.Tag="{Binding Source={x:Reference textBox1}, Path=Text}">
  <Label.Behaviors>
    <Behaviors:LabelDisplayBehavior />
  </Label.Behaviors>
</Label>
```

However, I get an error in the output window saying:

> SetValue: Can not convert  to type
>   'Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject'

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried making the TagBehaviour class derive from BindableObject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating an attached property of type `BindableObject` which you try to bind to the property `Text` of the `TextBox` which is of type `string`. Obviously, `string` cannot be casted to `BindableObject` hence the error.

Instead, declare your attached property of type `string`, or if you want to stay more general, of type `object`:

```
public class TagBehavior
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty TagProperty = BindableProperty.CreateAttached<TagBehavior, string>(
           bindableObject => TagBehavior.GetTag(bindableObject),
           null, /* default value */
           BindingMode.OneWay,
           null,
           (bo, old, @new) => TagBehavior.OnCompletedChanged(bo, old, @new),
           null,
           null);

    public static string GetTag(BindableObject bindableObject)
    {
        return (string)bindableObject.GetValue(TagBehavior.TagProperty);
    }

    public static void SetTag(BindableObject bindingObject, string value)
    {
        bindingObject.SetValue(TagBehavior.TagProperty, value);
    }

    public static void OnCompletedChanged(BindableObject bindableObject, string oldValue, string newValue)
    {
        //var tag = TagBehavior.GetTag(entry);

        //if (tag != null)
        //{
        //    Debug.WriteLine("TODO - Handle tag's value change event");
        //}
    }
}
```